# How to put an html <a> inside a json object?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm creating a json object. How to make this :

```
{
  "paragraphe_with_link"  : "hello, click <a href="myPage.html">here</a> to visit my page"
}
```

I want to have a simple sentence with clickable "here" in blue standard color, how to do that with json object please ?

Thank you

Comment: Use single quotes inside. If passing HTML, Better be encoded.

Comment: You can escape the quotes and the backslash like this: `"hello, click <a href=\"myPage.html\">here<\/a> to visit my page"`

Comment: Besides my comment I strongly agree with @Tushar's second sentence. Encoding is the better option.

Comment: @cale_b Found exact duplicate, so closed. Regarding encoding there are many questions on SO. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pass+HTML+in+JSON)